# Appending a string to all values in an array field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection filled with docs that contain an "ip_addresses" field, which is an array of strings (IPs). I want to append '/32' to all of these values in all of my docs that don't already have a CIDR range suffix.

Here's my issue:

1. I don't know how to use the current value of the IP which is being iterated on.
2. Even if I did, $concat doesn't seem to work and throws an error even with placeholder values (as in the query below) - `The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concat' in 'ip_addresses.0.$concat' is not valid for storage.`

Here is my current query which throws the error:

```
db.getCollection('docs').update(
    {},
    { $set: { "ip_addresses.$[ip]": { "$concat": [ "1.1.1.1", "/32" ] } } },
    {
        arrayFilters: [ { "ip": { $not: /.+\/\d{1,2}/ } } ],
        multi: true
    }
)
```

I'd appreciate help using the current values in the array in the $concat command and resolving the error.

Answer (score 0):

Let's tackle each of the problems.

2 -  [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) is an aggregation operator, hence it cannot be used for an update. you can view the list of available operators for an update [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1). You might notice that none of these "work" on actual document values which brings me back to the first question you had.

1 - In order you use a current document values within an update you have to use [pipelined updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) which is only available for Mongo v4.2+, if you're using a lesser Mongo version you have to fetch the documents into memory and do the update one by one in code. If you are on Mongo v4.2+ then the pipeline update syntax goes like this:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {ip_addresses: {$exists: true}},
    [
        {
            $set: {
                ip_addresses: {
                    $map: {
                        input: '$ip_addresses',
                        as: 'ipAddress',
                        in: {
                            $cond: [
                                {
                                    $regexMatch: {input: "$$ipAddress", regex: /.+\/\d{1,2}/}

                                },
                                '$$ipAddress',
                                {
                                    $concat: [
                                        '$$ipAddress',
                                        '/32'
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```